How to avoid circular depenedcies with combineSlices in Redux-toolkit?
I cannot avoid circular dependency when using combineSlices with createAsyncThunk condition.
I have a thunk that initiate my store:
thunk.ts
export const initiateFx = createAsyncThunk<
  InitiatePayload,
  string,
  { state: RootState }
>(
  'initiate-fx',
  async (dashboardId, { dispatch, fulfillWithValue }) => {
    const data = await fetchToSomeApi();

    return fulfillWithValue(data);
  },
  {
    condition: () => true
  }
);

And I have a lazy injected slice:
store.ts
declare module '@shared/redux/store' {
  // comment: resolve typings for lazy loading slices
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  export interface LazyLoadedSlices extends WithSlice<typeof slice> {}
}

export type State = {
  data: Data;
  isInitialized: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean;
};

const initialState: State = {
  data: null,
  isInitialized: false,
  isLoading: false,
};

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'my-slice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: () => initialState
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(initiateFx.pending, (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    });

    builder.addCase(initiateFx.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.data = action.payload;
      state.isInitialized = true;
      state.isLoading = false;
    });
  },
  selectors: {
    selectIsInitialized: (state) => state.dashboardId,
    selectIsLoading: (state) => state.isLoading,
    selectData: (state) => state.data
  }
});

export const { actions, selectors } = slice.injectInto(rootReducer);

I want to add condition in my thunk to prevent unnecessary requests
// ...
{
  condition: (_, { getState }) => {
    const state = getState();
    
    const isLoading = selectors.selectIsLoading(state);
    const isInitialized = selector.selectIsInitalized(state);

    return !isLoading && !isInitialized;
  }
}
// ...

I get a circular dependency store.ts -> thunk.ts -> store.ts

To eliminate the dependency cycle between the two files you'll just need to use separate selector functions that are not declared in the slice file.

Inline example:
export const initiateFx = createAsyncThunk<
  InitiatePayload,
  string,
  { state: RootState }
>(
  'initiate-fx',
  async (dashboardId, { dispatch, fulfillWithValue }) => {
    const data = await fetchToSomeApi();

    return fulfillWithValue(data);
  },
  {
    condition: (_, { getState }) => {
      const state = getState();

      const isLoading = state.[...path...].isLoading;
      const isInitialized = state.[...path...].dashboardId;

      return !isLoading && !isInitialized;
    }
  }
);


Functions:
const selectIsInitialized = (state: RootState) =>
  state.[...path...].dashboardId;

const selectIsLoading: (state: RootState) =>
  state.[...path...].isLoading;

export const initiateFx = createAsyncThunk<
  InitiatePayload,
  string,
  { state: RootState }
>(
  'initiate-fx',
  async (dashboardId, { dispatch, fulfillWithValue }) => {
    const data = await fetchToSomeApi();

    return fulfillWithValue(data);
  },
  {
    condition: (_, { getState }) => {
      const state = getState();

      const isLoading = selectIsLoading(state);
      const isInitialized = selectIsInitialized(state);

      return !isLoading && !isInitialized;
    }
  }
);



